# One-digit and two-digit separation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of values some of which are one digit (e.g, *5*), and some which are two digits (e.g, *55*) in cells.

For the calculation I want to make, I want to use the first digit of the values. I don't have a problem with two digits.

How can I make Excel use "**0**" if it is a one digit number without adding "**0**" in front of "**5**" in this example.

I mean I don't want to change the values and add 0 in front of them. How can I do that if it is possible?

Simply, I want excel to use "0" as the first digit, if it is a one-digit number. thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this formula: `=INT(A2/10)`

[image: excel table of sample data]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to do this with =Left() function. I didn't know about =int(). thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

[Máté Juhász's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1173101/348859) using `INT` is probably the best solution. However, for the sake of curious future readers, there is another, clunkier way:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT("0"&A2,LEN(A2))))
```

If your data ever goes up to more than two digits and you really want the tens place, not just the first digit, then `INT` will fail. In that case, you can use this clunky version. If you want to pull the tens place for any number, it gets messier.

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(A2,"00"),LEN(TEXT(A2,"00"))-1)))
```

[image: Examples]

Comment: =INT(MOD(ABS(A2),100)/10) - Although depending on use case the abs might not be wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use an IF statement since you're only concerned about a different rule if 1 digit (therefore, less than 10).

This is the cell value in C1

```
=IF(A1<10, 0 + F1, LEFT(A1,1) +F1)
```

It may seem odd to write `0 + F1` but I'm not aware of what logic you're using so 
I left it in to demonstrate the formula.

[image]